# browse to the Tomcat installation directory in the Eclipse mars version

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I installed `apache-tomcat-8.0.35` in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0`.

I am trying to cofigure the Tomcat in the Eclipse `Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)` but after clicking the following `Window-->Prefereces-->Server-->Runtime Environments-->add--> Apache Tomcat v8.0`-->(here I can click finish or cancel also I can not click the next button to browse to the Tomcat installion directory).

can someone explain me what can I else do to get it to work?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Normally I should get a window as the first image where I can click the next button then I will get image like this one below which I got from youtube tutorial:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to your question**

1. You are almost done, as a next step you need to map your tomcat installation directory (i.e up-to Tomcat 8.0 only, shouldn't include bin directory). Image given below. ***Please remember you should have appropriate Tomcat 8 adapter which is pre-built on Eclipse Mars, If not available, you won't be seeing your next button visible.*** You can also get it downloaded from Eclipse Market Place.

[image: TomcatServerConfig]

2. Click next button, your server (your project facet) will identify for web projects in your IDE and that can be directly deployed into your server. This may take some time which purely depends upon your size of the web project. Sometimes at this stage your IDE have a probable chance of getting hanged.

[image: Project COnf]

3. Add all -->Click Finish Button.

Comment: but  in my case after clicking the tomcat version the next button is always disabled and I can not click it please see the first image.

Comment: You don't have appropriate adapter for Tomcat 8 server to be created.

Comment: I searched for the `adapter for Tomcat 8 ` in the Marketplace and I did not found the same name but I found this one `Eclipse JST Server Adapters (Apache Tomcat, ....)`. I installed it and it works now. Thanks :)